# Validating Xml against an xml schema in C# from a Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, portable-class-library, xsd-validation

I need to validate XML stored in a custom format (not an `XmlDocument` or `XDocument`) in a C# portable class library.

The `System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator` class looks like it would fit the bill since it does not rely on a particular format - the calling code pushes data into it. However, I don't believe that it is available in a PCL profile that includes Windows/Windows Universal, Xamarin for iOS and Android.

How can I validate an xml document against an xml schema in this situation?